# What is "development mode?" How do I enable this so I do not have to shut down my server to see changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is "development mode?" How do I enable this so I do not have to shut down my server to see changes?

Comment: Is this a Rails question? If so, you should add "ruby-on-rails" to your the tags.

Answer (score 0):

When running your server, you can force development mode using

```
RAILS_ENV=development script/server
```